# Is this true? $(1+1/n)^n=1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+1/4!+\cdots + 1/n!$

Tags: proof-writing

Is this true? $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+1/4!+1/5!+\cdots $$($n$ times) or ($n+1$ times)?

If yes how to prove it and were there any proof of it?

Comment: No, this is not true - just try evaluating both sides for $n=3$

Comment: Did you try to actually evaluate it for some small $n$?

Comment: That two sequences have the same limit doesn't mean they're equal

Comment: in fact i made a mistake, i missed a one.

Comment: i corrected it now

Comment: Still wrong. The dots on RHS suggest a limit (it's the number e=2.718..., irrational number), while on the LHS there is a rational number, function of $n$.

Comment: Even for $n=2$, the left side is $(1+1/2)^2=\frac 94$, while the right is $1+1/1!+1/2!=\frac {10}4$

Comment: [(1+1/n)^n where n is the number you think about] of thanks

Comment: Coincidentally, I was wondering the same thing a little while back. You might be tempted to think it's true, but it isn't. However, it is true that the terms become closer and closer as n grows larger and larger. But they are never equal.

Comment: I think about nothing, thanks. If you want to write a limit, write it (or if you don't know how to write a limit in latex, ask us to write it). Here it's just mathematical rubbish.

Comment: @Ross sorry I didn't recognize your comment...

Comment: @user123456789 : your title does not match your question.  Your title has a finite sum, and the right-hand side of the equation in your question is an infinite sum, whether this is what you intend or not.  You should fix your question for the sake of future readers of this question.

Comment: @draks...:  I evaluated each side of the equation out to $n=2$ and found they did not agree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it not true.

Apply [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):
$$
  \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} \frac{1}{n^m} = \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{n (n-1) \cdots (n-m+1)}{n^m} \frac{1}{m!} = \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1}{m!} \prod_{k=0}^{m-1} \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right) 
$$

Answer (score 4):

While the way you posed the question is not true, a slight modification yields something like you want. 
The LHS is a well known limit and the RHS is the Taylor polynomial (evaluated at 1).
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\bigg|_{x=1}
$$
As others have pointed out, these two sequences have the same limit, but there is no guarantee they are equal term for term.

Comment: proof please?? please

Comment: The original question did not have the limit applied.  They are not equal except in the limit.

Comment: I agree. I should answer the question as written, not as I think it should have been written, right! ;)

Comment: OP, any undergraduate text should provide the details you need.

Answer (score 3):

No and evaluating $n=2$ would have been enough to see this:
$$
\left(1+\frac12\right)^2=1+1+\frac14=2.25 \neq 2.5=1+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}
$$

Comment: I personally prefer a simple, explicit counterexample like the one you gave.