# Evaluate using logs

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\lim_{k\to\infty} (1+\frac1k)^k$
Is there another approach to this solution other than l'Hôpital. Here's my working till now:
$$\ln\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k=k\ln\left(1+\frac1k\right).$$
As $k\to\infty$, $\ln(1+\frac1k)\to0$ due to the fact that $\ln(1)=0$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612155/is-this-true-11-nn-11-11-21-31-4-cdots-1-n

Comment: Damn mobile keyboard, the edit summary should have been "introduced LaTeX into post; corrected spelling of L'Hôpital".

Comment: Sorry for presenting such a bad quality.I know nothing about using LaTex.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k=e^{k\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)}$$

Using the integral definition of the logarithm function, $\log (1+z)\equiv\int_1^{1+z}\frac{1}{u}\,du$, it is easy to see that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{z}{1+z}\le \log(1+z)\le z$$

Therefore, setting $z=1/k$, we have

$$\frac{k}{k+1}\le k\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)\le 1$$

Using continuity of the exponential function along with the squeeze theorem reveals

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k=e$$

Comment: I have not yet still been introduced to integrals. okay i know what the squeeze theorm is but why does log lie within these two boundaries.

Comment: Well, help me to understand what you've studied so that we use only those tools you have at your disposal.  Else, I'm guessing how you're expected to proceed.  Do you know the mean value theorem and how to take the derivative of the log?

Comment: What i have studied so far limits,continuity, derivatives of exponential s and logarithms,trigonometric functions and their inverse functions that's it.

Comment: Do you know the derivative of the log function?

Comment: yes the derivative of ln(x)=1/x

Comment: OK.  Then, what is the limit $\lim_{k\to \infty}k\log \left(1+\frac1k\right)$ if you change variables and let $k=1/h$?

Comment: lim 1/h-->0 1/hlog(1+h)=lim1/h-->0log(1+h)/h thats the slope of the log at x=1, not sure though.

Comment: Yes.  And you know the slope is given by the ...

Answer (score 0):

As $h\to 0,$ $[\ln (1+h)]/h = [\ln (1+h) - \ln 1]/(h-0) \to \ln '(1) = 1.$ This is just from the definition of the derivative; no L'Hopital was used.

Comment: I get that this comes from the definition of a derivative but why is ln(1+h)/h-->1 as h-->0.

Comment: I assumed we know $\ln'(x) = 1/x.$

Comment: @zhw.  I'm not sure as to which tools the OP has.  Often, the limit is taken as the definition of $e$.  And it is easy to show that $\left(1+\frac1k \right)^k$ is increasing monotonically and bounded above by $3$ (and below by $2$.